# Maple Tree Question

Tags: trees, maple, sap

I have attached pictures of a maple tree.  I am curious to know what type of maple it is.[image: leaves of tree]
[image: bark of tree]

Second question...can this type be tapped for syrup?

Comment: Hi aclpilot, Is this maple tree growing inside the trunk of another kind of tree? there will probably be a struggle between these in the forthcoming years...

Comment: No, the large tree is a maple as well.

Comment: Please take a picture of the entire tree and include pictures of the leaves in the canopy.  I think J. chomel was worried the leaves in this picture are different than your whole tree.  A few more pictures will help to get a more viable solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I do believe this tree can be tapped for syrup.  Acer rubrum. [Red Maple](http://www.pfaf.org/user/Plant.aspx?LatinName=Acer%20Rubrum)

Let's wait until others have had a chance to concur or negate.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a black or sugar maple. I think syrup depends more on the temperatures , not the type of maple. I made syrup 2 years from silver maples in the Chicago area. I made a couple quarts from 2 trees. It is a 16:1 ratio from the juice ( NOT sap). On a bright sunny day after a below freezing night the juice flowed heavily . A cloudy day following a night in the 40's produced no juice. In March , the juice stops . I was actually starting to worry how to stop juice flow before it weakened the trees .